# onClick new input box add not working angularJs issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add dynamic form fields in the database using PHP. I have used angular to add dynamic form fields. The thing is when I am trying to insert this data into the database only last form field is inserting in the database. SO, I used array and loop to increment and update this form field into the database. but somehow query is not working properly and data is also not inserting into the database. can you tell me what is wrong here? I am stuck. Please help. Thanx in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group " >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Campaign Name" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="camp_name"> </div>
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">Start Date
                <input type="date" placeholder="start date" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="start_date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">End Date
                <input type="date" placeholder="end date" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="end_date"> </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-8 control-label">Select Store</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 c-margin-b-20">
                    <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme" multiple="multiple"  name="store">
                        <option value="1">All Stores</option>
                        <option value="2">Phoenix Mall</option>
                        <option value="3">1MG Mall</option>
                        <option value="4">Orion Mall</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row col-md-12" ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Elements</label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Campaign Name" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="ele"> 
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
                        <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme"  name="store">
                            <option value="1">All Stores</option>
                            <option value="2">Phoenix Mall</option>
                            <option value="3">1MG Mall</option>
                            <option value="4">Orion Mall</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <button  class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" ng-click="addNewChoice()" >add</button>
                    <button   ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" >Remove</button>
                    </fieldset>  
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" name="description">
    </div>
    <input class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square" value="Submit" type="submit">

</form>



// angular script

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
};

$scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
};

});
</script>
```

Comment: First, it seems there is two buttons for every choice no?
Second, in Angular, if you change the data, the whole page is rewritten, it's not a reactive framework.

Comment: So what do i do now?

Comment: I have solved this. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is simply take input type and put its type="button". It won't refresh your page. You were not specifying any type that's why it was taking type="submit" and the whole page was reloading. So avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<button type="button" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold 
c-btn-square" ng-click="addNewChoice()"> add</button>
```

You should always specify button type, otherwise, it will take submit by default and that's why it is refreshing the page.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it helped. I understood my mistake.